# Scala sealed class subclassing in external projects

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Quoting the documentation of Scala:

> A sealed class may not be directly inherited, except if the inheriting template is defined in the same source file as the inherited class. However, subclasses of a sealed class can inherited anywhere.

If I create a hierarchy of sealed classes in my project it's all fine, e.g.:

```
sealed abstract class Base {}
sealed class Derived extends Base {}
```

But what if I compile the project and distribute it as a, say, JAR in Maven.

What if I write a Java class in a 2nd project that has that JAR on classpath:

```
public class Breaker extends Derived {}
```

Will it compile aka will the constrait still hold? What if I wrote `Breaker` in Scala?

If *sealing* works in the abouve situations, how is it implmented?

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have a concept of `sealed` templates, therefore it is simply impossible for the Java compiler to enforce `sealed` constraints, because it doesn't even know they exist.

This is not specific to `sealed` and not even specific to Scala/Java. This kind of thing *only* works if both languages know about each other (i.e. the Scala compiler needs to know about every programming language that could conceivably be used to interoperate with it, *including* ones that don't even exist yet, and vice-versa, every compiler and interpreter for a language that could conceivably be used to interoperate with Scala needs to know about Scala, even compilers that were written before Scala existed) and they can agree on a a way to communicate those semantics between each other.

Of course, having all languages know about all other languages is O(n²) and doesn't scale, and obviously having languages know about languages that don't exist yet is just impossible. So, what we do instead is to define a common language that all languages know about. On Unix, that's C structs + C function calls, on the CLI, that's CIL byte code and on the Java platform, that's JVM byte code.

This means that Scala and Java can communicate with each other via a detour through JVM byte code, but obviously they can only communicate semantics which can be expressed in JVM byte code. And `sealed` is not one of those.

**Scala uses an annotation to encode `sealed` in the byte code, but Java doesn't understand that annotation, and even if it did, it doesn't actually cleanly map to any concept in Java anyway! (Unlike, say, Java interfaces which cleanly map to fully abstract Scala traits).**

Comment: The very last paragraph of your answer is all I was looking for. You could highlight it out more! Two more questions follow up: **1)** if I tried extending `Derived` in Scala having only compiled JAR on classpath would the compiler scan the class files? Does javac scan class files for some purpose as well? **2)** is `sealed` present in Scala from the first version?

Answer (score 1):

Given an empty `sealed` class and an empty normal class, the difference of the `javap` dump is in the value of `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` so I think the Scala compiler uses Java Annotations to discriminate the `sealed` classes.
If you want to investigate more:

- [Java annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)
- [JSR-175](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=175)

Thus, **as long as the Scala compiler is concerned**, that should be regardless of the distribution method.

The `javap` dump of the derived class doesn't change, by the way.

Comment: I believe that's limited to Scala and you can break the seals with Java or other JVM languages, until _All Hell Breaks Loose_.